# Getting error whenever i try to assign role to user in Identity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

here I am again..
I am trying to assign roles to the users which are registerd but whenever i try to update user details like assigning role i am getting role list required error. I try to debug the code but i didn't work. Need help from seniors!

View side code:
[image]

Controller side code:
[image]

Application user class which is inherited from identity user:
[image]

This is the output i getting:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation error message has already explained the problem. When you submit the form, you only fill in the three fields of `Name`, `Email` and `RoleId`, but the `Role` and `RoleList` are not filled. Make these two fields nullable if you don't intend to populate them when the form is submitted:

```
[NotMapped]
public string? Role { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem>? RoleList { get; set; }
```

Comment: Oh, I got it bruh. Thank you so much bruh it works. I am thinking about that but didn't pay attention to this. Once again thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @Mohamad Usman, If my answer helped you solve your problem, could you please accept it as an answer?